# Math Class troubles

Tags: java

Declare an int variable with the identifier *minInt* and assign it the value of the smallest int variable x, y, or z using the min method of the Math class. You may need to use multiple statements or method calls to accomplish this.

It said previously that x, y, and z were all declared so I don't need to worry about that.

But this is my code for this question and I don't see where I'm going wrong.

```
int minInt = min(x, y);
```

If x and y were declared before I don't have to assign it a value correct?

> Uncompilable source code - cannot find source code

is the error I'm getting.

Comment: Post all your code and the error you're getting

Comment: Don't post all of your code. Post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you sure that the error doesn't say "cannot find symbol" rather than "cannot find source code"? Also, you should add whether this is a RuntimeException (which it probably is) or a compile-time exception. And you're probably using NetBeans, are you not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it you're not calling the Math classes static method because otherwise the code would look like this..

```
int minInt = Math.min(x,y);
```

Currently it looks as if you'd be calling your own classes min method, which I am assuming there isn't one.

Comment: how would you answer this?

Comment: Theres multiple questions, maybe thats my issue I have to answer all the questions before I can run it for an accurate result. Give me a little bit to answer the other parts.

Answer (score 0):

Store the minimum of `x` and `y` first into `minInt` then find the minimum between `minInt` and `z`, store it into `minInt`. Print the value for verification.

You are using an `public` `static` method of **Math** class, so You need to use the class name as well along with the method. `Math.min(x,y);`

```
int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
int minInt;
// Assign the values to x, y, and z.
minInt = Math.min(x, y);
minInt = Math.min(minInt, z);
System.out.println(minInt);
```